# Squares of sum of digits of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I encountered the following property:

If you take a number, add up its digits, square it, take the resulting number, and repeat the process after a finite number of steps, you will get 1, 81, 169, or 256 only as the answer.

(Actually, the 169 and 256 will keep alternating.)

For all numbers I tried, it was true, but I could not prove it mathematically.

Also, the answer would be 81 if the number is divisible by 3, but again I cannot prove it.

Can anyone give me a hint as I would like to complete it myself?

Comment: Did you know that we can check for divisibility by $9$ by adding up the digits of a number and checking that for divisibility by $9$?  Do you know why that works?  Can you use that knowledge to help here?

Comment: If $f(n)$ is the sum of the squares of the digits of $n,$ then $$f(n)\leq 81\left(\lfloor \log_{10} n\rfloor +1\right).$$ So you will likely only need to check a finite set of values $n.$

Comment: For example, if $n>1000,$ then $f(n)<n.$

Comment: So you only need to check $n$ for $n<1000.$ But then $f(n)\leq 81\cdot 3=243,$ so you only really need to check $n\leq 243.$

Comment: For heuristics see https://oeis.org/A177148

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I would have thought $243$ may be too low and instead you want $(9+9+9)^2 = 729$.  We know $f(169)=256$

Comment: Whoops, yes, I defined $f$ wrong. The approach is good, but you'll have $f(n)<81\lceil\log_{10} n\rceil^2.$ But this will give a somewhat harger upper bound. @Henry

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well you might argue: $(9+9+9+9)^2 = 1296$ and $(1+9+9+9)^2 = 784$ and $(7+9+9)^2 = 625$ and $(6+9+9)^2 = 576$ and $(5+9+9)^2=529$, at which point it may be worth looking at individual values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We prove two lemmas:

1. Any limiting cycle consists of either a single number or an alternation between two numbers.
2. The limiting cycle must include a number less than or equal to $441$.

**Lemma 1**

This is based on the fact that if we have a cycle of $n$ numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$, then each must satisfy

$a_k\equiv(a_k)^{2^n}\bmod 9.$

Superficially the exponent may be any of $2,4,8,16,...$. However, note that the Euler totient of $9$ is $6$ and that the maximum exponent on any prime factor of $9$ is $2$. These properties guarantee that for all integers $a_k$ we must have

$a^{6+2}=a^8\equiv a^2\bmod 9,$

and thus implies that for any $n\ge3$:

$a^n=a^8\equiv a^{n-2}\bmod 9.$

So if we propose a $3$-cycle, then we propose $a_k\equiv(a_k)^8\bmod 9$, only to find from the Euler-totient based congruence that this also implies $a_k\equiv(a_k)^2\bmod 9$. The $3$-cycle thereby reduces to (three copies of) a $1$-cycle meaning a single number. Similarly a $4$-cycle reduces to a $2$-cycle, a $5$-cycle reduces to a $3$-cycle and then a $1$-cycle, and so on. Any proposed even cycle length reduces to $2$ and any odd cycle length reduces to $1$.

Note that in all cases the reduced cycle length properly divides the proposed one.

**Lemma 2**

For this lemma we consider two cases. First suppose that the limiting cycle is just one number. Then this number satisfies

$a_1=a_1^2\bmod 9.$

But the squared sum of digits in $a_1$ must be less than or equal to $[9(1+\log_{10}(a_1))]^2$. So we must also satisfy

$a_1\le[9(1+\log_{10}(a_1))]^2$

and this holds only for numbers having four or fewer digits. A five-digit number has a squared sum of digits no greater than $2025$ and so must be reduced accordingly.

Now comes the fun part. If $a_1$ has no more than four digits, then the maximum sum of digits it can have is $36$ whose square is $1296$. So the limit cycle must include a number less than or equal to $1296$. In turn, that has a maximum digit sum og $27$ (corresponding to $999$), so the bound reduces further to $27^2=729$; and then numbers less than or equal to $729$ have digit sums less than or equal to $24$ (from $699$) reducing the bound now to $24^2=576$. After a couple more iterations the bound finally stabilizes at $21^2=441$, so the limit cycle in this case nust contain a number than or equal to $441$ (which would then be the only number since this is a $1$-cycle).

In the second case, where the cycle has two numbers, we must start with

$a_k=a_1^4\bmod 9$

$a_k\le[9(1+\log_{10}(a_k))]^4$

This time the inequality allows numbers up to eight digits; but then such a number must have a digital sum squared less than or equal to $72^2=5184$. This bound for the minimum of the two numbers in the cycle has only four digits and is covered by Case 1, so again the bound stabilizes after the descent process at $441$.

**Endgame**

So now we know that any proposed cycle must contain only squares and a minimum of $441$ or less. We can reduce the trials further by noting that the square roots must have residues $\in\{0,1,4,7\}\bmod9$, these being the residues satisfying $x^2\equiv x$ or $x^4\equiv x\bmod 9$. The remaining candidates are easily checked by computation leading to the claimed cycles

$\overline1,\overline{81},\overline{169,256}.$